# Handling multiple events on single serial port in Arduino

Tags: arduino, gps, serial-port, bluetooth-lowenergy, gsm

I am working on an Arduino project where I am using only an integrated module for GPS,GSM and Bluetooth.
I am getting the response of all these devices on single serial port where bluetooth and SMS event can occur at any time but when they occur it disturbs the current data on serial port data and does not detect any new bluetooth event or any new sms event.

```
    void loop(){
  while((digitalRead(6)==LOW)&&(q==0));
  { 
delay(1000);
Serial.println("Reading SMS");
    while ( Serial3.available() > 0) Serial3.read();   // Clean the input buffer 
       memset(response,'\0',250);
      memset(sms,'\0',11);
      memset(number,'\0',14);
    readsms();
      q++;
  }


  if((digitalRead(6)==HIGH))
{
 q=0;
perform the normal operation
}

  while(digitalRead(7)==HIGH);
if(digitalRead(7)==HIGH)
{
  blepair();    //function to pair a new device with bluetooth
  delay(1000);
  }

if(digitalRead(7)==LOW)
{

  blestatus();     //monitoring any new event via bluetooth
  delay(1000);
 }
```

All the data I am getting on same serial port.
What are the options available for overcome this problem.
I would really appreciate your early responses.

Comment: Are GPS/GPRS and Bluetooth embedded on single device? If no then you can use [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library from arduino to configure extra serial port on arduino.

Comment: GPS/GPRS and Bluetooth is on single device.